# Canvas snippets for sublime or atom text editor

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How can i convert those textmate snippets for sublime or atom..

https://github.com/johnhunter/JavaScriptCanvas.tmbundle

And please What is the best text editor for developing canvas application that support autocomplete and live preview.

Comment: JetBrain's WebStorm has everything you want for JavaScript/canvas development (IMO). It has a TextMate plugin too but I'm not sure what it does in regards to TM snippets.

Answer (score 0):

### I got it :)

I tried to make this package for Atom and it works fine.

Also think the orginal snippets i've shared above works fine in sublime, i've just tried it.

https://atom.io/packages/canvas-snippets

if someone found more packages can help within developing canvas apps please post it here :) 
here.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's Something I made for SublimeText.

### [Canvas Snippets](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Canvas%20Snippets)

#### Features

- Has every methods and Property of the Canvas' Context
- And more snippets to initialize and get started setting up canvas
- Also has some commonly used code
- Has some Math objects property too
- A CheatSheet to look up tab triggers